# Certificate error after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: ssl, 20.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 19.10 to the latest 20.04. After this process, doing HTTP calls passing a certificate gives the following error:

`error: Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate', 'ca md too weak')]`

Executing

`openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -noout -text | grep 'Signature Algorithm'`

returns the following:

`sha1WithRSAEncryption`

The OpenSSL version installed is 1.1.1f

Can this behaviour overridden? If not, is it possible to downgrade to a compatible openssl version?

Comment: It says your message digest (your hash function) is too weak. You need to update your code to use something better than SHA-1.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232849/how-do-i-resolve-an-ssl-handshake-error-in-the-snap-store

Comment: I got my `curl` and `wget` SSL errors solved by following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level It did not fix my `pip` SSL error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution, according to the accepted answer of this question: [Ubuntu 20.04 - how to set lower SSL security level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level)

In particular, the openSSL configuration file `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` shall be modified in the following way.

At the beginning, add `openssl_conf = default_conf`

At the end, add

```
[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = ssl_default_sect

[ssl_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
```

After this modification, the certificate is recognized without security errors.