# How do I resolve an SSL handshake error in the snap store?

Tags: 20.04, ssl

When I open the snap store, I get an SSL handshake error. How can I fix that? I had a clean install of ubuntu 20.04 from an iso. Any help would be welcome. I never had this problem in 19.10 or 18.04.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231799/certificate-error-after-upgrade-to-20-04

Comment: I got my `curl` and `wget` SSL errors solved by following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level It did not fix my `pip` SSL error.