# When I try to CURL a website I get SSL error

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, tls

I installed Ubuntu 20 on my VPS. This is why I'm trying to do:

```
curl -v https://imenik.tportal.hr/show?action=pretraga&type=bijeleStranice
[1] 438975
root@vps:/var/www/html/tportal# *   Trying 195.29.166.100:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to imenik.tportal.hr (195.29.166.100) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, protocol version (582):
* error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

But when I try like this, it kinda works

```
curl -v http://imenik.tportal.hr/show?action=pretraga&type=bijeleStranice
[1] 438977
root@vps:/var/www/html/tportal# *   Trying 195.29.166.100:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to imenik.tportal.hr (195.29.166.100) port 80 (#0)
> GET /show?action=pretraga HTTP/1.1
> Host: imenik.tportal.hr
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 07:44:32 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
< Location: https://imenik.tportal.hr/show?action=pretraga
< Content-Length: 336
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://imenik.tportal.hr/show?action=pretraga">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at imenik.tportal.hr Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

I can't find a solution to this SSL problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Website uses the old TLS protocol version 1.0, which has been [disabled by default since Ubuntu 20.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls28/+bug/1856428).

To temporarily override the default for your `curl` command, you can create a config file somewhere (e.g. `~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf` with following content:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Then run your command like this:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf curl -v https://imenik.tportal.hr/show?action=pretraga&type=bijeleStranice
```

(this will only set `OPENSSL_CONF` for that single command)

or

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf
curl -v https://imenik.tportal.hr/show?action=pretraga&type=bijeleStranice
```

(this will only set `OPENSSL_CONF` for the current session or script)

You *could* also set it globally in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, but it has been disabled for good reasons and I would only override that when necessary.

([via](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls28/+bug/1856428/comments/2))

Comment: This fixed the problem :) Thank you very much. If I want to go back to original configuration, I should do this: `export OPENSSL_CONF= /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, the environment variable is only valid until you close the terminal or to the end of the script. But, if you **still want** to change back in the current session, you can just run `export OPENSSL_CONF=` (set blank). Or just use the first command in my answer, setting the env var in the same line as the `curl` command, then it is only valid for that single command.

Comment: Great. One last question, how do I set it globally in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` since I need it for longer period of time? I did it like this
`[ system_default_sect ] CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1`

but it's not working

Comment: I would say you can just add the whole thing at the end (not tested). But can't you just run `export OPENSSL_CONF=~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf` whenever you need it?

Comment: That is actually good idea, I'll try it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Edit the `openssl.conf` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Add this line at the top:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init
```

And add these lines at the end:

```
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

It works for me. :)

For the Laravel, also run

```
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Comment: This also works if you have an Apache 2.4.41 with https proxy to an old server (e.g. Apache 2.2). No changes in Apache needed after upgrade to Ubunto 20. Just this `openssl.cnf` change and reboot.