# Python's test_ssl fails starting from Ubuntu 20.04. I need to find a person at Canonical responsible for openssl configuration

Tags: python, openssl, tls

Please take a look at https://bugs.python.org/issue41561. Developers who work on Python think that the issue is due to a change in Ubuntu 20.04 that is best described by https://bugs.python.org/issue41561#msg378089:

"It sounds like a Debian/Ubuntu patch is breaking an assumption. Did somebody report the bug with Debian/Ubuntu maintainers of OpenSSL already?
Fedora also configures OpenSSL with minimum protocol version of TLS 1.2. The distribution does it in a slightly different way that makes the restriction discoverable and that is compatible with Python's test suite."

Question: who at Canonical can help with this issue?

Comment: Seemingly relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level

Comment: You can find the list of patches, and the patch committers, at https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl. Most of those committers hang out at discourse.ubuntu.com. If you raise an issue at d.u.c, the devs first question will be for a link to the bug report.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level is indeed relevant, but it it seems more like a workaround rather than a solution. In any case, thank you. I posted a question on .../openssl.