# Ubuntu 22.04 problem with eduroam

Tags: 22.04

I have upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately I cannot use my university eduroam net now. The WiFi works very well, but it is not possible to use the eduroam. I cannot log in.
I have tried some solutions from

[Ubuntu 22.04 cannot connect to Eduroam](https://www.linux.org/threads/ubuntu-22-04-cannot-connect-to-eduroam.39939/)

[Cannot connect to eduroam since 22.04 update](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ufalf4/cannot_connect_to_eduroam_since_2204_update/)

without success.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eduroam doesn't connect due to weak certificate signature digest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406525/eduroam-doesnt-connect-due-to-weak-certificate-signature-digest)

Answer (score 1):

this reference from our ICT department worked for me: leave everything as-is for ubuntu 22.04 OS, but tell wpa-supplicant (specifically) to work with a 'less strict' version:

[How to connect to WPA2/PEAP/MSCHAPv2 enterprise wifi networks that don't use a CA_Certificate, like Eduroam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c/1405397#1405397)

I rebooted and I then had to 'edit' the eduroam entry inside wifi settings, because the settings somehow now contained 'ca.pem' as a certificate, while you should (as far as I know) select 'no CA certificate needed' for eduroam.
So after selecting 'no certificated needed', my laptop connects to eduroam again.

btw: the ethernet at our university also didn't work anymore after the upgrade to 22.04; also this is repaired now for me (probably wpa-supplicant is used for both wifi as well as ethernet?).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there be a problem between openssl 3 (implemented in wpa_supplicant v2.10) and LTS. The experts recomend evetually downgradding to the wpa_suplicant v2.9 until this bug will be fixed.

Here you are a url wheere you can download a v2.9 release:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.9-1ubuntu4.3_amd64.deb

After the corresponding dpkg excuted, you have to restart the system and the eduroam should work succesfully

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I tried everything in this page and also the page referenced in the comments. However, what solved my problem is changing tunelled lts to peap and suddenly it connected. (you need ca.pem file provided by university which you can download from their website, it will be a py file that installs the pem file to .config)