# Ubuntu 22.04 - how to set lower SSL security level?

Tags: 22.04, openssl

While using Ubuntu 20.04, the solution for lowering security and allow acces to some outdated servers I used the following solution [Ubuntu 20.04 - how to set lower SSL security level?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level).

Today I upgraded to 22.04, and the solution won't work any more. I tried some other config file tweaks, but with no success. After some reading I guess it has something to do with the latest openssl 3 installed in Ubuntu 22.04.

Is there a way to be able to use legacy methods in openssl 3, as we did in 20.04?

Comment: I asked the same on Questions for Ubuntu but still received no response: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/703140

Answer (score 3):

It works if you change the security level to 0 instead of 1. In the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` change SECLEVEL from 2 to 0:

```
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```